# Visual Studio 2008: How to publish a website and what are the requirements. It's my first time so please send me detail instructions

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How to publish a website and what are the requirements.  It's my first time so please send me detail instructions.

Comment: there are so many ways to publish / deploy and a lot of them depend on your environment your deploying to. The best thing is to get your deploy as automated as possible. One click deploys rock and will save you pain.

Comment: FTP, WebDav, Copy / Paste, etc. What kind of access do you have to the web server this project will live on?  Also, do you have any dependencies that are required to be installed on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on web project, scroll down - Publish!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it via the Build menu.